# does function.php get overwritten on theme update?

Tags: wordpress

I've got to add some php functions to a theme so they can be used from different pages.  The docs say one place to add custom php functions is in function.php

Cool!

My question is, what happens when I update a theme?  Will the functions.php containing my changes be overwritten by a new one - thereby wiping out all my hard work?

My gut says yes but before I go and create a child theme I figured I'd ask to be sure.

Thanks

Mark

Answer (score 7):

I'm just adding my 2 cents because this was the first Google result that came up when I was searching for the same question.  Yes, your functions.php will be overwritten with a theme update.

I solved the problem by downloading the code-snippet plugin.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/code-snippets/

Now I can easily add and manage functions that won't be overwritten.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if *all* the files are overwritten when the theme is updated, or only the changed files, but your changes will definitely be lost at some point in the future.

From [Using the Theme Editor and Plugin Editor](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_Files#Using_the_Theme_Editor):

> Be aware that if the theme you edit is updated, your changes will be overwritten. To better organize your changes and protect them from updates, consider creating a Child Theme in which to keep all your changes.

Comment: All files are replaced: the theme is downloaded as a zip package, a folder is created inside `wp-content/upgrade`, the original removed and the new one moved into place. If the theme eventually created folders in `/wp-content/whatever`, these are kept untouched.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're talking about -only- modifying functions.php, writing a plugin is probably a better option. Creating a plugin basically involves writing a few lines of text to create the header, which includes the plugin name and so forth. Then adding your code and... that's it. Plugins are highly portable, you can use them on other sites. Also, if you switch themes, your code doesn't disappear.

(I'm not anti-child theme, am just presenting an alternative.)

https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin

Comment: He didn't ask that. You can offer a solution to put his modifications elsewhere. But he asked if `functions.php` is overwritten or not during theme updates.

Answer (score 0):

You should add one more another functions.php file in same directory.
Example: functions2.php
You can add any code you want in the second file. Then in the main file "functions.php", all you need to do is add this code:

```js
include 'functions2.php';
```

That's it! Even you update your theme or update Wordpress, your file "functions2.php" still remain. All you need to do is add single line in "functions.php" to make it works again.